# How do I add an angular directive as an attribute to a child node

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom angular directive wrapping an html element:

```
<my-directive-1>
    <div some-attribute="some value">My original content</div>
</my-directive-1>
```

Which will compile to add another directive as an attribute to the child node:

```
    <div some-attribute="some value" my-directive-2>My original content</div>
```

Such that the controller for `myDirective2` will be triggered on the child node.

How can this be done?

Comment: Any chance you could provide the code for the `myDirective1` directive so that I can give you a working example of how this can be done?

Comment: Well, I'm basically rewriting it to only accomplish this task. I'm deprecating ```myDirective1``` in my app so that future users can just use ```myDirective2``` on the base element instead of using ```myDirective1``` as a container. The goal with this is to allow backwards compatibility so that people don't have to refactor their code if they upgrade.

Comment: Too easy. Checkout my answer, should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$compile` in this case so that Angular knows it is a directive. Angular will compile this, acknowledging that there are things such as directives, data, and other things that need compiling for the scope.

Firstly, overwrite the elements HTML with the new HTML. Secondly, use `$compile` to compile the elements new contents with Angular, in relation to the `scope`.

```
app.directive('myDirective1', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.html('<div some-attribute="some value" my-directive-2>My second content</div>');               
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
}]);

app.directive('myDirective2', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.html('<div some-attribute="some value">My final content after two directives</div>');
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/vGwyGJ)

Comment: Ok, the ```$compile``` is definitely putting me on the right track, but I want to preserve any other attributes that may exist on ```div```. Instead of ```element.html(...)``` I tried ```element[0].querySelector('div').setAttribute('my-directive-2','')``` and then ran $compile, which actually works but it results in ```<div ... my-directive-2="">```. Is there any other way to dynamically add ```my-directive-2``` attribute to ```div```?

Comment: @Matt - So your question is how to have `my-directive-2` on the element instead of `my-directive-2=""`?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. All the accepted answers I'm seeing use the setAttribute method I'm using, but that appears to be adding an empty string as the assigned value.

Comment: @Matt - `my-directive-2` is equal to `my-directive-2=""`, there is no difference at all with them, the directive `myDirective2` will still be called on both of them. Some browsers will add an empty string to the attribute while others will not.

Comment: Ok cool. This worked like a charm for me. Like I said, I just used ```element[0].querySelector('div').setAttribute('my-directive-2','')``` instead of ```element.html(...)```. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt - Glad I could help :)